# How can I fix runtime Error of my this code?

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java. I am trying to solve the following problem using java language.

> You are to write a program that reduces a fraction into its lowest
>   terms.
>
> Input
>
> The 1st line of the input file gives the number of test cases N (<=
>   20). Each of the following N lines contains a fraction in the form of
>   p=q (1 <= p; q <= 10^30).
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output the fraction after simplification.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4
> 1 / 2
> 2 / 4
> 3 / 3
> 4 / 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 / 2
> 1 / 2
> 1 / 1
> 2 / 1
> ```

My little approach is:

```
package bigfraction;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
                int n = num.nextInt();
                int i;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String input1 = s.next();
                    String d1 = s.next();
                    String input2 = s.next();

                    // convert the string input to BigInteger
                    BigInteger val1 = new BigInteger(input1);
                    BigInteger val2 = new BigInteger(input2);

                    BigInteger gcd = val1.gcd(val2);
                    BigInteger q1 = val1.divide(gcd);
                    BigInteger q2 = val2.divide(gcd);
                    System.out.println(q1+" / "+q2);
                }
    }

}
```

I am getting runtime error when I submit exact the code in online judge. This is my first submission in java language. I am unable to fix the runtime error.

Comment: Hi, please provide the error message as well, in ideal case the most of the stacktrace- there is usually the row number which causes the error, thanks

Comment: What are the inputs which is you entered  ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're reading the file wrong, because you have whitespaces in between the fractions, and you can't convert them

Comment: @Lino then what is the correct way of reading the file in this term?

Comment: @user9248520 well it depends on the inputs you're giving to the programm. You said something from *input file* but in your main method you're using the standard `System.in`.

Comment: I am trying but can not modify it may be for lacking in the knowlegde of java specifically. Could you please provide with the modifications?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, just the thing is you can't read a file with system.in. Either google how to parse your sample input from file correctly into your code (maybe you can use map or something like that, also I'll suggest to remove white spaces in the input file) or accept the inputs from keyboard as System.in accepts inputs from keyboard.

Also try to print proper message which value you are going to accept next before accepting it.

one more thing is you don't need multiple scanner objects, you can accept as many inputs from single scanner as you want. Also the variable `d1` seems to be unused, remove it if you're not using it

Comment: I am trying and getting output all fine when i run this code in my IDE(netbins) but it shows RTE when I submit in OJ .@amol_shaligram

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out the solution just now.Now it is accepted.
My accepted code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{       

            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
                int n = num.nextInt();
                String extra;
                int i;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                    extra = num.nextLine();
                    String input1 = num.next();
                    String d1 = num.next();
                    String input2 = num.next();

                    // convert the string input to BigInteger
                    BigInteger val1 = new BigInteger(input1);
                    BigInteger val2 = new BigInteger(input2);

                    BigInteger gcd = val1.gcd(val2);
                    BigInteger q1 = val1.divide(gcd);
                    BigInteger q2 = val2.divide(gcd);
                    System.out.println(q1+" / "+q2);
                }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Lino commented, this works fine as long as you write your faction in the format that the task specified. If you use whitespaces (2 / 4 instead of 2/4) in between the fractions you will receive the simplification.

Comment: what do you mean by *receive the simplification*?

Comment: @Lino The output